# Crosscompiling my Linux QT Project with MXE fails. Library not found

Tags: c++, qt, taglib, mxe

I have a QT5 Project on Linux using taglib. It compiles fine inside QtCreator and runs flawless under Linux.

Now I want to Crosscompile the code using MXE. I've downloaded and "installed" MXE according the docs. I did a "make" for making all libraries crosscompiled. I also set my PATH as described in the docs.

the qmake run makes no errors, but when i "make" the project, the compiler complains:

```
./tagprocessortaglib.h:12:21: fatal error: fileref.h: No such file or directory
#include <fileref.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
```

fileref.h is one of the library headers used by taglib, its furthermore the first of 3 includes of that lib.

In my .pro file, this two lines were added by QtCreator as i included the library for linux:

```
unix: CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
unix: PKGCONFIG += taglib
```

Are there any configurations to do for the library that I've missed? Any help is welcome! Thanks in advance!

**Solved the issue:**
I applied the Solution posted here: [Compiling QT project for win32 target on Linux PC with larmadillo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715721/compiling-qt-project-for-win32-target-on-linux-pc-with-larmadillo?rq=1)

and added the path to the library, this works for the MXR compiler run, but i have to remove it before native compiler runs.

Comment: Since taglib compiled fine, it is likely you are missing an include path. Have you compared the include paths of taglib with the paths of your app?

Comment: Like i said: it compiles fine under native Linux/QtCreator with the shared system libraries. The Problem comes up, when i compile with the mxe environment (static).

Comment: as the headerfile is embraced by <..h> the compiler should automatically find the header in the library pathes.